# How to pass token as a parameter in axios

Tags: react-native, axios

In postman i pass **connectapitoken** as the key and **1234567890** as the token which fetches the data but i dont understand how to pass it in the header unlike **Bearer token** to fetch the data.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```
…
headers: {
 connectapitoken: ‘1234567890‘
}
…
```

Comment: Yes it works. Really appreciate it